# ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36, or 0 - Kol - Smirnov test

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to do a Kolmogorov - Smirnov test. I took 10k numbers from linear congruential generator.

```
def kolmogorov_smirnov_test( data_set, confidence_level, num_samples ):
# Step 1:  Rank data from smallest to largest, such that:
# R(1) <= R(2) <= R(3) ... <= R(i)
data_set.sort()

# Step 2: Computer D+ and D-
# D+ = max(i/N - R(i))
d_plus = get_d_plus_value_for_KS_TEST(data_set, num_samples)
print("D+ VALUE =" +(str(d_plus)))

# D- = max(R(i) - (i -1)/n)
d_minus = get_d_minus_value_for_KS_TEST(data_set, num_samples)
print("D- VALUE=" +(str(d_minus)))

# Step 3:  Computer D = max(D+,D-)
d_value = max(d_plus, d_minus)
print("D VALUE (max): " +(str(d_value)))

# Step 4: Determine critical value, using table
# Step 5: Accept or reject Null hypothesis
return d_value
```

and it is giving following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-8ab28c7d697e> in <module>
----> 1 kolmogorov_smirnov_test()

<ipython-input-28-087123eac877> in kolmogorov_smirnov_test()
      8     # Step 2: Computer D+ and D-
      9     # D+ = max(i/N - R(i))
---> 10     d_plus = max (int(data_set, num_samples))
     11 
     12     # D- = max(R(i) - (i -1)/n)

ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36, or 0
```

Comment: The code in the error does not match the code in your question. The error is telling you that you are calling `int()` with the second argument `base` with too large a value. `int(data_set, num_samples)`

Comment: Make sure you have saved the code in your IDE before you attempt to run it, and when you get an exception, make sure that the code cited in the exception matches code that you actually have. Otherwise there's no way to tell what you're actually debugging.

Answer (score 1):

`int` as a function takes two parameters: The value that shall be converted to an integer and the base for this number (e.g. `int("FF", 16)` would result in 255). So `int(data_set, num_samples)` wants to take `num_samples` as the base, which would be complete nonsense.

But that is not the only problem. The first parameter in `int(data_set, num_samples)` is your data-array, which cannot be converted to an integer (at least not in that way).

And even if (for some wierd reason) this whole function could return an integer, `max(int(data_set, num_samples))` would then get a single integer as a parameter, which also does not work.

The bigger problem is now, that the code doesn't even remotely match the given mathematical function, so that i cannot help you any further until given more information about what your actual goal here is.